# Insert table in arabic document

Tags: tables, arabic

How to insert table in arabic document (using arabtex package)?
The table also contains arabic text.
I tried to use tabular in arabtex environment, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far in terms of LaTeX coding. By the way, is the screenshot a representation of what you've tried so far or of what you'd like to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. It is easy to put `arabtex` quotation (`\< >`) in every cell in the table.
I thougt it would be more simple if I could put `tabular` within `arabtex` environment.

Comment: As suggested to you in a comment, could you please explain your problem more clearly, and your solution as well? This website uses everyone's questions and answers as reference for users who will face the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage {arabtex}

    \novocalize
    \begin {document}

        \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|} }\hline 

            \RL{f}      & \RL{.d}   & \RL{.htn_A}   & \RL{tb'u_h}  \\ \hline 
            \RL{b}      & \RL{a}    & \RL{l}        & \RL{lA}       \\ \hline
            \setverb \RL{'w}        & \RL{m}    & \RL{y}        & \RL{a}        \\ \hline
            \RL{.st}    & \RL{bsy}  & \RL{lA}       &\RL{s}         \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}



\end{document}
```